# Column name as a parameter in INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create one **stored procedure** where i want to insert values in a table. 
But i don't know in which field i have to insert values and at the 
**runtime i will decide in which field the values should be inserted**. 
What i want to do is

```
insert into Tablename(@ColumnName, Description) 
values (@ColumnValue, @MH_Description)
```

Can it possible that i pass this type of parameters in stored procedure as shown in the example above??

I want to use conditions too as

> declare @Query nvarchar(4000)
>       declare @Query1 nvarchar(4000)
>       declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
>
> ```
> set @Query = '
>     insert into tbl_temp(' + quotename(@ColumnName) +',Description)
>
>     values (@ColumnValue, @Description)'
>     set @Query1 = '
>     update tbl_temp set' + quotename(@ColumnName) +'=@ColumnValue, Description=@Description'
> set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100),@Description varchar(100)'
> if exists(select 'true' from tbl_temp where quotename(@ColumnName)=@ColumnValue)
> begin         
>   exec sp_executesql @Query1, @ParmDefinition, @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue, @Description = @Description
> end
> else 
> begin      exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, @ColumnValue= @ColumnValue, @Description = @Description
> end
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible to do with parameters. You will need to build dynamic query to achieve this.

The proc that uses dynamic SQL would look like this:

```
create procedure MyProc
(
    @ColumnName varchar(100),
    @ColumnValue varchar(100),
    @MH_Description varchar(100)
)
as
begin
    declare @Query nvarchar(4000)
    declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

    set @Query = '
        insert into Tablename(' + quotename(@ColumnName) +',Description) 
        values (@ColumnValue, @MH_Description)'
    set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @MH_Description varchar(100)'
    exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue, @MH_Description = @MH_Description
end
```

[EDIT] Answer to your second question. Make it one query instead of two

```
set @Query = '
    if exists(select * from tbl_temp where '+quotename(@ColumnName)+' = @ColumnValue)
        update tbl_temp set' + quotename(@ColumnName) +' = @ColumnValue, Description=@Description
    else        
        insert into tbl_temp(' + quotename(@ColumnName) +',Description)
    values (@ColumnValue, @Description)'
```

Comment: Can dynamic query is possible in MVC action controller. If yes, then please can u tell me how?

Comment: @Saloni - it is does not matter where you use it MVC, ASP.NET, WinForms or WPF. Just call the proc through whatever data access you are using.

Comment: i want to use conditions as well like this

Comment: @Saloni - you can easily add conditions. Just follow the sample.

Comment: @Alex Aza- i m not getting this can u please explain how?