# How do I use an SQL value as its column name in a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table with Orders (one record per order) and a table with OrderDetails (one record per product in order). I'd like my SELECT statement to return the quantity of each product in a column named with the ProductID. This way I am not explicitly writing out a query for each ProductID, but let the query adapt to whatever ProductIDs it finds in the OrderDetails table.

The result would then be something like:

```
OrderID   TrackingNr   ProductID1   ProductID2   ProductID3
1         1Zetc        6            0            2
2         1Zetc2       0            1            1
```

I have the following currently:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID AS OrderID,
TrackingNumbers.TrackingNumber AS TrackingNumber,
(SELECT Quantity FROM OrderDetails WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID AND ProductCode = 'FPIA0009') AS FPIA0009,
(SELECT Quantity FROM OrderDetails WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID AND ProductCode = 'FPIA0030') AS FPIA0030,
((SELECT Quantity FROM OrderDetails WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID AND ProductCode = 'FPIA0060') +
(SELECT Quantity FROM OrderDetails WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID AND ProductCode = 'FPIA0060xP')) AS FPIA0060,
(SELECT Quantity FROM OrderDetails WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID AND ProductCode = 'FPIA0120') AS FPIA0120
FROM Orders, TrackingNumbers WHERE Orders.OrderID = TrackingNumbers.OrderID
ORDER BY OrderID, ShipDate
```

You can see, above I'm explicitly requesting quantities for each specific ProductID, but there are many more and I'd rather have this simplified.

You can also see, I attempted to add  up the quantities for two different products, since they draw from the same stock, but for some reason the result is always empty.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is not possible:
"You will need to build dynamic query to achieve this."
see code in the link...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449409/column-name-as-a-parameter-in-insert-statement

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL server, MySQL?

Comment: bluefeet: I presume it's MySQL, I only have access through a query field. The database is part of Volusion's shopping cart.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function but you can model it using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement. For a dynamic version, you will need to use prepared statements.

Sample Tables used:

```
create table orders
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);

insert into orders values
(1, 'Order 1'),
(2, 'Order 2'),
(3, 'Order 3'),
(4, 'Order 4');

create table orderdetails
(
  orderid int,
  productname varchar(20),
  qty int
);

insert into orderdetails values
(1, 'Product 1', 10),
(1, 'Product 2', 1),
(1, 'Product 3', 45),
(2, 'Product 1', 2),
(2, 'Product 5', 78),
(3, 'Product 4', 60),
(3, 'Product 2', 32),
(4, 'Product 1', 5),
(4, 'Product 3', 6),
(5, 'Product 2', 9),
(6, 'Product 4', 1);

create table trackingnumbers
(
  orderid int,
  trackingnumber varchar(10)
);

insert into trackingnumbers values
(1, '1Zetc'),
(2, '1Zdfghfdg'),
(3, '1Zkyui'),
(4, '1Zwe');
```

If you know the number of values that you want as columns, then you can hard-code the values similar to this:

```
select o.id,
  t.trackingnumber,
  sum(case when productname = 'Product 1' then qty else 0 end) Product1,
  sum(case when productname = 'Product 2' then qty else 0 end) Product2,
  sum(case when productname = 'Product 3' then qty else 0 end) Product3,
  sum(case when productname = 'Product 4' then qty else 0 end) Product4,
  sum(case when productname = 'Product 5' then qty else 0 end) Product5
from orders o
left join orderdetails d
  on o.id = d.orderid
left join trackingnumbers t
  on o.id = t.orderid
group by o.id, t.trackingnumber;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9225f/17)

But if you have an unknown number of values, then you can use prepared statements:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when productname = ''',
      productname,
      ''' then qty else 0 end) AS ',
      replace(productname, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM orderdetails;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT o.id, t.trackingnumber, ', @sql, ' 
                  from orders o
                  left join orderdetails d
                    on o.id = d.orderid
                  left join trackingnumbers t
                    on o.id = t.orderid
                  group by o.id, t.trackingnumber');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9225f/15)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do it like that but..  you can always just create the SQL using a Cursor and execute it.  That way at least it is not hard coded.  I would definitely recommend not using values for column names though.

Comment: I'm building a report that calculates the fulfillment fees for a given period. Since the fulfillment costs differ per product I need to know each product shipped separately, or even better, each product group (where three different productIDs draw from the same stock in different quantities, i.e. 1 * ProductID1 = 1 SKU, 1 * ProductID2 = 3 SKUs). My first attempt was to hard-code it all, but I stranded when trying to add up these values, so I decided to deal with that in Excel (where the CSV export report is for) and just get each product in their own column.

Comment: select SUM(quantity) from TABLENAME group by PRODUCTGROUP - just throwing ideas out...